# sock file is missing in running django app with nginx and gunicorn

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04) and successfully ran the project manually. However, after setting up nginx and systemd, it says `502 Bad Gateway`.

I have looked through other similar threads to no avail.

I see that my gunicorn workers are running by doing `ps -ax | grep gunicorn`.

my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/myproject;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

and the systemd file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/myproject
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject.sock   myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The contents of `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

```
2017/02/18 17:57:51 [crit] 1977#1977: *6 connect() to unix:/home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.2.2, server: 172.30.1.5, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject.sock:/", host: "localhost:8000"
```

Manually running `/home/ubuntu/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject.sock   myproject.wsgi:application` is also working. That is, sock file is created.

I feel like I missing something very simple.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There could be an ordering thing here - nginx is probably starting before gunicorn, so the socket is not yet there to connect. You should add `gunicorn.service` to the `After` directive in the nginx systemd file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Daniel. I tried to change `/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service` and restart nginx. But it did not help. Still see 502 Bad Gateway